# "Uncaught at retriveFormData" error even though there are none in reference to my first document call

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

```
function retriveFormData(inputFormUrl) {
  var inputForm = FormApp.openByUrl(inputFormUrl);
  var iFId = inputForm.getId()
  var iFRespond = inputForm.getPublishedUrl();
  var iFItems = inputForm.getItems();
  var inputFormData = [iFId,iFRespond,iFItems];
  document.getElementById("iFId").value = inputFormData[0]
  document.getElementById("iFRespond").value = inputFormData[1]
}
```

The above function is called from the code below from a script tag inside some html after the user clicks a button.

```
function getData() { var inputFormUrl = 
  document.getElementById("inputFormUrl").value; 
  google.script.run.retriveFormData(inputFormUrl); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function retriveFormData(inputFormUrl) {
      var inputForm = FormApp.openByUrl(inputFormUrl);
```

FormApp is a serverside google apps script

```
      var iFId = inputForm.getId()
      var iFRespond = inputForm.getPublishedUrl();
      var iFItems = inputForm.getItems();
      var inputFormData = [iFId,iFRespond,iFItems];
      document.getElementById("iFId").value = inputFormData[0]
```

document.getElementById() is a clientside javascript method

```
      document.getElementById("iFRespond").value = inputFormData[1]
    }
```

There is no scope where both of these can exists in the same function.  I assume that your trying to retrieve form data from an html form.  This isn't the way to do that.  FormApp is a class that interacts with Google Forms.

Comment: No, I am working with Google forms. Should I switch the clientside into its own function for it to work?

Comment: If you can share some more of the code I'll show how you can connect them with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: The function is inside the .gs file. I need to update the html based on what the FormApp call returns.                                                                                        
   function getData() {
      var inputFormUrl = document.getElementById("inputFormUrl").value;
      google.script.run.retriveFormData(inputFormUrl);
    }                                                                                                                                 getData is inside a script tag and is called when the user clicks a button.

Comment: Originally, the document calls were inside the html, but when I returned the data it gave me undefined. That is why the document calls were in serverside. Essentially, I can't figure out how to update the html based on what FormApp returns.